# SQL - Get Nth row based on other variable

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to to get the Nth completed trip_id (unique per trip) per driver. For example, the 3rd completed trip of every driver_id (unique per driver), with my database table which looks like:

```
id    datetime    driver_id  trip_id   trip_status
---|------------|----------|---------|--------------|
1  | 03/03/2009 | 1111     |   1     |  completed   |
2  | 04/03/2009 | 1111     |   2     |  cancelled   |
3  | 05/03/2009 | 2222     |   1     |  completed   |
4  | 05/03/2009 | 2222     |   2     |  completed   |
5  | 06/03/2009 | 2222     |   2     |  cancelled   |
6  | 06/03/2009 | 2222     |   4     |  completed   |
7  | 06/03/2009 | 3333     |   1     |  completed   |
8  | 06/03/2009 | 3333     |   2     |  completed   |
9  | 06/03/2009 | 3333     |   3     |  completed   |
```

And wish my result to be like:

```
id    datetime    driver_id  trip_id   trip_status
---|------------|----------|---------|--------------|
6  | 06/03/2009 | 2222     |   4     |  completed   |
9  | 06/03/2009 | 3333     |   3     |  completed   |
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Stack Overflow can help, but **will not write your code for you**. What have you tried so far? Share your queries along with where *specifically* you're getting stuck in those attempts.

Comment: @esqew So basically I need to try do the SQL query, but I'm a Python user. The idea I had was to filter first by counting the number of "completed" per driver_id to leave those with 3 or more, but stuck in showing only that 3rd observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to get row numbers for recoreds as ordered by `datetime` partitioned by `driver_id`.

```
SELECT id,
       ...
       trip_status
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    ...
                    trip_status,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY driver_id
                                       ORDER BY datetime) rn
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE trip_status = 'completed')
       WHERE rn = 3;
```